# Can't access value from a nested Hashmap

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

Retrieving this set of data from Firebase and i'm unable to get the value of the user_description section.

Firebase data

[image]

```
final DatabaseReference fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    DatabaseReference complaint = fb.child("complaints");
    complaint.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : data.getChildren()) {
                Complaint complaint = child.getValue(Complaint.class);

                String key = complaint.complaint_description.keySet().toString();
                String desc= complaint.complaint_description.get(key).get("user_description");
                Log.v("ComplaintFragment", desc);

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.v("ComplaintFragment", databaseError);

        }
```

Receiving an error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the Complaint class

```
public class Complaint implements Serializable  {

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> complaint_description;
String complaint_id;
String complaint_subject;
String facility_name;
String facility_type;
boolean fixed;
int join_staff;
int join_student;
int join_total;
String location_area;
String location_floor;
String note;
boolean sent;
String user_id;

public Complaint() {
}

public Complaint(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> complaint_description, String complaint_id, String complaint_subject, String facility_name, String facility_type, boolean fixed, int join_staff, int join_student, int join_total, String location_area, String location_floor, String note, boolean sent, String user_id) {

   //initialization
}

//set and get methods here
```

}

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to use `Log.v("ComplaintFragment", key);`, what does it return?

Comment: @AlexMamo The issue is   `Log.v("ComplaintFragment", complaint.complaint_description.get("-LDXSyVDoMIT01vs9GTV"));` 
 returns   {user_id=l5JtSqF9wgUfpUbSl6oKONO0poB3, user_description=wow}  but`Log.v("ComplaintFragment", complaint.complaint_description.get("-LDXSyVDoMIT01vs9GTV").get("user_description");` returns the error     `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null because your database reference is wrong

you are accessing to your main tree node complaints

```
DatabaseReference complaint = fb.child("complaints");
```

but you need to access one more node that is your user id

```
DatabaseReference complaint = fb.child("complaints").child(uid);
```

remember that the uid can be retrieved with FirebaseAuth

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

mAuth  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

let me know if this work

Comment: Hi, the issue i'm facing now is that   `Log.v("ComplaintFragment", complaint.complaint_description.get("-LDXSyVDoMIT01vs9GTV"));` 
 returns   {user_id=l5JtSqF9wgUfpUbSl6oKONO0poB3, user_description=wow}  but  `Log.v("ComplaintFragment", complaint.complaint_description.get("-LDXSyVDoMIT01vs9GTV").get("user_description");` returns the error     
 `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: the thing is that the object user_description is not in your Complaint.class, you need to add it, so when you try to get that value you are not getting any reference to it

Comment: so sir, what should I do?

Comment: just add user_description to your POJO class Complaint.class and then when you retrieve the value store it in there , please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597084/how-do-i-retrieve-multiple-items-of-data-from-firebase-and-merge-these-strings-t

Comment: glad it worked buddy, if you feel like this answer was helpfull dont forget to mark it as correct or a thumb up , that will help me keep answering and also tell to others that maybe are in the same situation that this answer could work for them too. Happy coding !

Comment: that's for sure :) do have a nice day!